# Как подсветить элементы в react native на полупрозрачном фоне?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь сделать вывод подсказок для определённых элементов на экране. По дизайну надо чтобы на полупрозрачном фоне определённые прямоугольники не были прозрачным.
Какие есть приёмы для этого ? Или может уже есть какие-то готовые решения в виде пакетов?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по картинке это модальное окно. Вы можете установить **react-native-modal**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal.